# How to force byte compile a directory in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to byte compile a directory forcibly without caring about anything in elisp source (means the same as the interactive one: <kbd>C-u 0 M-x byte-recompile-directory</kbd> but in source)?

Need I write something like:

```
(defun byte-compile-directory-recursively (directory)
  (dolist (file (directory-files directory t "\\w+"))
    (if (file-directory-p file)
        (byte-compile-directory-recursively file)
      (if (string-match "\\.el$" file)
          (byte-compile-file file)))))
```

? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `(byte-recompile-directory directory 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've misunderstood sth and ask a stupid question. Now it's clear !